# A Windows DLL stored on Debian, then downloaded back to Windows won’t work anymore

Tags: windows, windows-8, debian, eclipse, dll

I have a program which I want to distribute through my webserver running Debian.

So I uploaded my files—containing DLLs—to the server. After I did let them download through my updating application I got an error. So I tried downloading them like I uploaded them: Via Eclipse IDE. But the error did also occur:

Title of the Error Dialog:

> Main.exe - Bad Image

Error:

> Blabla.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an
>   error […] Error status 0xc0000130.

So I am wondering what causes the DLL corruption. Has it to do with Eclipse or Debian?

**EDIT** The md5 checksums of the original, the uploaded and the downloaded file are different.

**EDIT2** It seems this is an issue between the codepage selected in eclipse which is UTF-8. I will test it with cp1250 (quick test did work so far, but my app crashed) in detail tomorrow.

**EDIT3** Also, my updater didn't work correctly interpreting the downloaded files as text files.

Comment: Very strange ... My first thoughts would be that Eclipse is doing something to the files :/ ... One way to find out where the file is being changed, is to get an MD5 hash of the file before uploading it, after uploading it, and after downloading it, and see where the change is happening.

Comment: The md5's are all the same. Guess i will try zipping tomorrow.

Comment: If the md5s are the same, then the contents are the same.  In other words, there's nothing wrong with the file.

Comment: Found that the md5-tool didnt work correctly (for whatever reason). Other md5-tools showed me a difference in the checksum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One typical reason may be an incomplete upload. Check the size of the uploaded DLLs, reupload if the size is smaller than expected.

Another reason is the file conversion between Windows and UNIX, which damages binary files when they are mistakenly transferred in text mode. I don't believe this is your case (since you seem to be using HTTP and not FTP), but it might be worth checking.

Otherwise you'll have to compare your original DLL compiled by Eclipse with the DLL you download from your webserver, and post the differences here for further analysis.

Comment: I do suspect that the file is mistaken for a text file. Probably the magic number at the start of the file gets modified that way, which causes the error message.

Comment: It seems to be the used file encoding which i did set to utf-8 in eclipse. I did a quick test by setting it back to cp1250. That seemed to be the trick. But i will verify this in detail tomorrow.

Comment: @Incubbus, encodings are for text files... eclipse should be treating it as a binary file... but again, if it had the encoding wrong and mangled the file as a result, its md5 sum would change.

Comment: @Incubbus, did you make sure that DLL files you're trying to distribute work in the first place, if you just copy them to your app? Maybe the issue is in the build process (if you build those DLLs), and/or in the interface compatibility between the application and those DLLs?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, i did build the DLLs myself , with the same tool i used to build the application (VS 2013). The app works fine if i don't use the downloaded files but those copied from my build output. Also, it does not make a difference if i run it using VS Debugger or without  VS.